# ExtJS: How to set dockedItems alignTarget

Tags: forms, extjs, alignment, uitoolbar

[image]

I added `dockedItems` to my `form.Panel`, it aligns to the form, but I want the dockedItems align to the `table` inside the form, how should I do.

Here is the demo: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3kso

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you set the viewport's layout to `fit`, and you also specify a fixed width for the table (300 px), the form is ordered to occupy the remaining area, and that's why the toolbar is at the left edge.

Although you could try to make the toolbar `floating` and align it the the table, I think it is easier to let the form take only the space it needs, and therefore the toolbar will we aligned to the form.

To do so, at the end of your fiddle, try this code to change the viewport's layout:

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'middle'
    },
    items: [form]
});
```

If you need the fit layout for some other reasons, you can keep the fit layout, and add the form within a container:

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'container',
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'middle'
        },
        items: [form]
    }]
});
```

Or if you need a panel that occupies all place, and you want a panel inside this with aligned toolbar, you can use and outside and an inside panel also (check the grey background to see the outside panel):

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        bodyStyle: {
            background: '#eeeeee'
        },
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'middle'
        },
        items: [form]
    }]
});
```

The important thing is that by using `vbox` and `middle` in the layout the form will only occupy the place it needs.

**EDIT 1**:

To address the issues in the comments, here is a complete example that can be run as fiddle:

```
const form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    autoScroll: true,
    bodyStyle: {
        background: '#abd1ca'
    },
    layout: {
        type: 'table',
        columns: 2,
        tableAttrs: {
            style: {
                width: '300px',
                'background': '#e3f2fd',
                'border-collapse': 'collapse',
            }
        },
        tdAttrs: {
            style: {
                border: '1px solid #ccc',
                padding: '6px',
            }
        }
    },
    fieldDefaults: {
        labelWidth: 40,
        width: '100%',
    },
    items: new Array(100).fill({
        fieldLabel: 'sample',
        xtype: 'textfield'
    }),

    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        dock: 'left',
        items: [{
            iconCls: null,
            glyph: 61,
            xtype: 'button'
        }, '-', {
            iconCls: null,
            glyph: 88,
            xtype: 'button'
        }, {
            iconCls: null,
            glyph: 70,
            xtype: 'button'
        }, '-', {
            iconCls: null,
            glyph: 47,
            xtype: 'button'
        }]
    }]

});

Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        bodyStyle: {
            background: '#eeeeee'
        },
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox',
            align: 'stretch',
            pack: 'middle'
        },
        items: [form],
        buttonAlign: 'center',
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Save',
            handler: 'save',
        }, ],
    }]
});
```

Comment: Awesome, but the button at the bottom doesn't display

Comment: And the dockedItems doesn't stick to top left.

Comment: @itsalongstory The button can be moved to the outer panel, and the margin causes that the toolbar is not at the top left. I will add a complete example to the answer shortly.

Comment: After run `EDIT 1:`, All looks good, except for an extra horizontal scroll bar, horizontal scrollbar is not necessary

Comment: I set a width to `tdAttrs`, removed the width of `tableAttrs`, The horizontal scroll bar disappears!!

Comment: Good to hear,  so now it works as you intended?